# How to connect AWS Elasticache Redis from a local machine for a Django project?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I've Redis chace installed on both my local and aws elasticache. My Django project runs well on my local machine with Redis. However, when I connect to my redis remotely on aws, I get the following error.

```
Error 10060 connecting to xyz.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I have the following Django settings for the local redis:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
        }
    }
}
```

And this the Django settings for the remote redis instance:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://xyz.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
        }
    }
}
```

Again, when I switch from local to remote caches settings, I get that error above.

I know that I it is not possible to connect ElastiCache outside AWS unless you have a vpn connection. So, I've set up the vpn client end point on aws and connected to it using the aws vpn client. I can successfully connect via vpn as shown below.

[image]

Also, if I run the following command under C:\Program Files\Redis on my command prompt window

```
redis-cli -h magicstat-redis.ysw0xy.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379 ping
```

I get this error.
[image]

Any idea why I still can't connect from my local machine to the remote redis on aws elasticache even though I can connect via vpn?

Comment: See [Accessing ElastiCache resources from outside AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you can't connect from your local machine. Elasticache is a service designed to be used internally to your VPC. External access is discouraged due to the latency of Internet traffic and security concerns.

Please refer this documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found out what was going on. As you can see from the screenshot below, I've added the custom 0.0.0.0/0 source. I can connect via VPN now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can only connect Elasticache Redis and MemoryDB from ec2 which is in the same VPC.